# Jersey Client can't post a header

Tags: java, rest, post, http-headers, jersey-2.0

I've got a problem to create a POST with Java and the Jersey(v.2.22) client api. I trie to send the session token to a server. With GET it's no problem:

```
...
Invocation.Builder builder=webTarget.request();
            builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
            builder.header("Token",token);
            builder.buildGet();
            try(InputStream inputStream=builder.get(InputStream.class);...
}...
```

But when I do the same for a POST:

```
Invocation.Builder builder=webTarget.request();
        builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        builder.header("Token",token);
        Response test=builder.buildPost(Entity.json(node.toString())).invoke();
```

I become a unauthorized response-
*InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=http://localhost:8080.../, status=401, reason=Unauthorized}}*

I tested the POST service with Ruby too. There were no problems with the token in the header. And it's the same token the GET service runs with.

Has somebody an idea i do wrong or is it a bug?

Comment: are you sure for POST, to send token in the header, maybe it should go in the body

Comment: Im sure booth ways should run, with Ruby I posted the token in the header and it runs.